# Forcing columns to show on smaller width screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a dashboard that will appear on a rotated display (800x1280) and want to use Bootstrap to simplify development. When I use columns, they end up stacking on top of each other due to the width of the screen.

How can I force the columns to display as they normally would, despite the reduced width?

EDIT:

Using `col-xs-*` and `col-sm-*` cause the items to stack, which I don't want.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- ... links to bootstrap etc. ... -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Try it out here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRvXYV . Open Chrome's dev tools, turn on the device toolbar, then set the size to 800x1280. The columns will stack.

Comment: Use `.col-xs-*` or `.col-sm-*` grid classes.

Comment: show your `HTML` code for better understanding of your issue.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman These cause the columns to stack, which I'm trying to avoid. I'm editing my Q to show some code, though there isn't really much to see.

Comment: cells may stack  because of absent wrapping `row`

Comment: @Banzay Looks like it needed to be `col-xs-*` with a wrapping `row` class.  This is odd because xs is for < 768px screens, and I'm definitely at 800px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, part stupidity on my part, part oddness from Bootstrap.

I needed to wrap the columns in a row, but on top of that, I needed to use `col-xs*` which the documentation states, is for devices < 768px wide. My display is definitely 800px wide and if it's not, is definitely not any lower than 768px.

Thanks to Banzay for the prompt for the row, but I'm still scratching my head over `col-xs-*`..

Comment: you can just define div by `col-xs-4` and nothing more. Cell width defined for xs will be inherited for all larger breakpoints: sm, md and lg. Cell width (e.g 4) defined for sm will be the same (4) for md and lg, but for xs it will be 12.

Comment: Or maybe your display is less than 800px. Maybe just you cheated in the store. :)